# Is there any way in Struts 2 by which I can get all namespaces in my app?

Tags: struts2, struts

Is there any way in Struts2 by which I can get list of namespaces in my App ?
I want this as set or list at runtime .

I am using Struts2 RestActionMapper plugin. 
When there invalid namespace is specified for valid action, Struts is throwing namespace error.
But I could not redirected to standard error page when this error occurs. I tried almost all options e.g.global error mapping default namespace etc . Nothing worked. So thought it would be great if I could get list of namespaces in my app, thus i could have checked invalid namespace against my list of valid namespaces and accordingly I could have thrown generic error which would finally result in my standard error page.

---

I am looking for how to get list of all namespaces in my project.
So basically I want to do something like  this.

validNamespaces = getNamespaces();

if(validNamespaces.contains(namespaceRetrivedFromRestPlugin))
   {Sysout("This is valid namespace.")} 
else 
   {Sysout("Invalid namespace");}

Comment: It sounds like what you really want to ask is how to customize the error page that the RestActionMapper is showing?

Comment: Thanks Steven. I am looking for how to get list of all namespaces in my project. So basically I want to do somtehing like  this.

Comment: I have added some more information in question under ------- Please go through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, though like Steven has pretty much stated, I'm not convinced that this is the right approach to the problem you state of redirecting to an error page.  But, I'll leave that part up to you and use this space to answer the namespace question.

This code will have to be in a Struts2-created object for the injection to work.

```
private Configuration configuration;

@Inject
public void setConfiguration(Configuration config) {
    this.configuration = config;
}

protected Set<String> getNamespaces() {
    Set<String> namespaces = Collections.emptySet();
    Map<String, Map<String, ActionConfig>> allActionConfigs = this.configuration.getRuntimeConfiguration().getActionConfigs();
    if (allActionConfigs != null) {
        namespaces = allActionConfigs.keySet();
    }
    return namespaces;
}
```

The configuration can also be obtained from a `ConfigurationManager`.  Also, you would obviously want to store these in a variable rather than calling above method over and over.  If your object is, say, an `interceptor`, then you could call this method from the `init()` method and store it in a class-level variable.

Comment: @iamon3 If it worked, any chance you could accept the answer for me?  I would appreciate it!  :D